# Python AES CTR to PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, aes

I try to make this AES CTR encryption (that work fine in python) in php

working python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import Crypto.Util.Counter
from Crypto.Util import Counter
key = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
encryptkey = bytes(key)
ctr = Counter.new(128)
crypto = AES.new(encryptkey, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
text = "E5ZA,K2JV,PA01,J1W3,386S,AGVZ,9O9T,F640,FR20,40LX,D443,1913,031V"
bytetext = bytes(text,'utf-8')
encryptedtext = crypto.encrypt(bytetext)
encryptedtext = encryptedtext.hex()
print(encryptedtext)
```

my php try

```
<?php
function strToHex($string){
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}

$bytes = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31);
$lkey= implode(array_map("chr", $bytes));
$method = "AES-256-CTR";
$password = $lkey;
$data = array("E5ZA", "K2JV", "PA01", "J1W3", "386S", "AGVZ", "9O9T", "F640", "FR20", "40LX", "D443", "1913", "031V");
$string= implode(array_map("chr", $data));
$valid = openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $password);
echo strToHex($valid)
?>
```

the error and wrong result I get

```
Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended in /test.php on line 16
387041417471684a6c74437032356f5477673d3d
```

the response I expect:

```
b5682cef66f2adaff0dacb7078f31a773feb86f28614b5ee24e9ee634200a8d6eb177a151eb55003c6cc81b3e9cb6d1a1673a2881ec194370af242d9f1fd5818
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes give different results for the following reasons:

1. In the Python code, the counter is assigned a size of 16 bytes. The initial value of the counter is 1 (by default). As already mentioned in the other answer [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503291/9014097), the PHP code lacks the IV. To get the same result in both codes, the *same* IV must be used in each case.
2. In the Python code the data are separated by commas. Therefore the comma must be used as delimiter when concatenating in the PHP code.
3. In the PHP code, the data (with regard to the subsequent hexadecimal encoding) must not be returned Base64 encoded, but as raw data, i.e. the flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` must be set.
4. When converting to a hexadecimal string, each value must be output with two digits, i.e. with a leading `0` if necessary.

The following PHP code contains the necessary changes and therefore gives the same result as the Python code:

```
function strToHex($string){
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $hex .= sprintf("%02s",dechex(ord($string[$i])));                        // 4. formatting                                                   
    }
    return $hex;
}

$bytes = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31);
$lkey= implode(array_map("chr", $bytes));
$method = "AES-256-CTR";
$password = $lkey;
$data = array("E5ZA", "K2JV", "PA01", "J1W3", "386S", "AGVZ", "9O9T", "F640", "FR20", "40LX", "D443", "1913", "031V");
$string= implode(",", $data);                                                    // 2. delimiter
$iv = hex2bin("00000000000000000000000000000001");                               // 1. right IV
$valid = openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);   // 3. raw data 
echo "Result:             " . strToHex($valid) . "\n";
echo "Result from Python: " . "b5682cef66f2adaff0dacb7078f31a773feb86f28614b5ee24e9ee634200a8d6eb177a151eb55003c6cc81b3e9cb6d1a1673a2881ec194370af242d9f1fd5818" . "\n";
```

By the way, instead of `strToHex` the built-in function `bin2hex` can be used.

*Note:* For CTR the reusing of an IV under the same key destroys security [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)). Thus, with the current implementation, a new key must be used for each encryption (since a fix IV is used). Another approach is to split the IV into a nonce and a counter, with the nonce being generated randomly for each encryption [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR))[[4]](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode).

Comment: thanks so much for all your explanation, that help me a lot to understand

Answer (score 1):

In openssl_encrypt you need An IV to make sure encrypted text is unique.

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$generatediv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
```

And after that

```
$valid = openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $password, 0, $generatediv);
```

Hope it's work

Comment: I think the OP is concerned here with what he has to change in the PHP code so that the result matches the Python code. But you' re right that a random IV should be applied, at least for a fix key, because it prevents multiple use of the same key/IV pair, which would destroy the security of CTR. Regarding your mcyrpt methods, please note that they are [_deprecated_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php).